# $wpdb->prepare is not working like mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress plugin and recently I have planned to migrate from SQL to `$wpdb`. I'm using a method called `$wpdb->prepare` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string` but it does not work.
Here is what I tried:

Code:

```
echo $fetch_row;
```

Output:

> a:5:{s:9:"task_name";s:10:"Backup Now";s:9:"mechanism";s:10:"singleCall"

Code:

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string( $fetch_row )
```

Output:

> 'a:5:{s:9:\"task_name\";s:10:\"Backup Now\";s:9:\"mechanism\"

After `mysql_real_escape_string` function executed you can see the difference in the string.

I came along [this question on stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144989/alternative-to-mysql-real-escape-string) so I used `$wpdb->prepare($fetch_row)`
but the output did not change, it is just like the input.

Suggest me where I'm doing mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i'm seeing is that you are trying to **sanitize** a Result and not an **SQL query**. Therefor this will return false by default since `wpdb->prepare()` checks for a string with sprintf/vsprintf format pattern.

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

And from what the variable contains you might want to check something more related to it.

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/

--
*will update upon more clarification*